# Having trouble passing property into drawRect in UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, swift2, drawrect

Not understanding why my property resets to the original value assigned (0.1). I pass in a fillHeight of 0.5 from outside method. The property is set in the convenience init, but does not carry over to the drawRect. What am I missing?

```
import UIKit

class MyView: UIView {

  var fillHeight: CGFloat = 0.1

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

  }
  convenience init(fillHeight: CGFloat) {

    self.init()
    self.fillHeight = fillHeight
    print("self.fillHeight: \(self.fillHeight) and fillHeight: \(fillHeight)")

  }
  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

  }

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    print("drawRect self.fillHeight: \(self.fillHeight)")
    // custom stuff
  }

}
```

Output on the console:

outsideAmount:Optional(0.5)

self.fillHeight: 0.5 and fillHeight: 0.5

drawRect self.fillHeight: 0.1

EDIT:
The outside call comes from UITableViewController with a custom UITableViewCell. The image is for the cell.

```
func configureCell(cell: CustomTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let myObject = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyObject

    cell.nameLabel.text = myObject.name
    cell.strengthLabel.text = myObject.strength

    cell.myView = MyView(fillHeight: CGFloat(myObject.fillAmount!))
    ...
```

MORE EDIT:

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var strengthLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var myView: MyView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
```

}

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error, but in my case it prints `drawRect self.fillHeight: 0.5`. Can you post the code where you initialize the view and add it to the view stack?

Comment: Thank you joern. I've added the call

Comment: Could you please post how you define the `myView` property in you custom cell? Is it an optional property?

Comment: MyView is the class that I listed above, not a property on the func configureCell. The call is with the convenience init. 'Cell' is not optional as it is a property of the function configureCell. 'myObject.fillAmount' is optional, as noted in the output console

Comment: But If you are doing `cell.myView = ...`, `myView` has to be a property of the cell. Because `UITableViewCell` does not have a property of that name.

Comment: So my question was: How do you define `myView` in your custom cell? Are you defining it `let myView: UIView?` or `let myView = UIView() ` ?

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood you. I've added the code. 'myView' is an IBOutlet that is not optional.

Comment: To be precise: `myView` **is** an optional, it's just that it's implicitly unwrapped so you can use it as a non-optional.

Comment: Also, Adding the your custom view to the cell during configuration seems overkill - Overtime you dequeue a cell you're setting the view. Why not do it just once when you create the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assign a new `MyView` instance whenever you configure your cell. You don't have to do that because the view is already there (because you added it in the nib).

So just set `fillHeight` on the cell's `myView`. That fixes the problem:

```
func configureCell(cell: CustomTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let myObject = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyObject
    cell.nameLabel.text = myObject.name
    cell.strengthLabel.text = myObject.strength
    cell.myView.fillHeight = CGFloat(myObject.fillAmount!)
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sticking with me!